# C# Move a Label from left to right

Tags: c#, timer, label

i'm wondering is there any solution to animate a label with a timer? I want the label2 to go slowly to the left until is hitting the label1 and when it's hitted, to go backward from where has started going to the left.
I tried this, but when is hitting label1 it's stopping:

```
       label2.Location = new Point(label2.Location.X - 4, label2.Location.Y);

        if (label2.Location.X == label1.Location.Y)
        {
            label2.Location = new Point(label2.Location.X + 4, label2.Location.Y);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing `label2.Location.X == label1.Location.Y`, which seems like a typo.

You need a direction variable and you need to store the original position of Label2 so it knows where to go to:

```
label2.Location = new Point(label2.Location.X + step, label2.Location.Y);
if (label2.Location.X <= label1.Location.X) {
  step = 4;
} else if (label2.Location.X >= originalX) {
  step = -4;
}
```

To setup your variables:

```
int step = -4;
int originalX;
```

and then use the Load override method to set the originalX value:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
  base.OnLoad(e);
  originalX = label2.Location.X;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are moving always left. Shouldn't you be using a variable to keep track of the direction you want to move.

In that sense, you need to check when you've reached the right margin to change direction again.

Comment: and how i supposed to check that?

Comment: By saving the initial value of the Location property of label2. That way you can check if you have reached the rigth limit. Another way, if label2 has to make it all the way back to the right border of your form is to check if label2.Location.X + label2.Width equals form.Width.

Comment: oke, but the label7 is going until reaches the whole label6, i mean is putting itself on it, and i want just to reach it's right part not the left one.